# Why does "ServiceCollection()" not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord.net

I am making a basic Discord Bot following a Blog i found online
I am using Dotnet 8 on VS Code on a C# .Net Core Console App.
I am a beginner what did i do wrong? Is the code deprecated?

Heres the Code Causing me Issues:

```
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration)
                .AddScoped<IBot, Bot>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();
```

I tried searching online for alternatives and there werent any and yes i am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependancyInjection.

If needed i can provide more code but the problem is caused by ServiceCollection() simply not existing so i dont think that would be necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `using` line at the top for the `ServiceCollection` class?

Comment: use the worker template from the command line: `dotnet new worker`  this will create you a new console app with DI wired up in the template. What we can't tell from your post is whether or not you are creating the `IHost` correctly, eg, `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` which manages the service collection that you are trying to create

Comment: Welcome to SO! Dependency Injection providers usually have a much more rich failure report, with exceptions, inner exceptions, stack... at least this should be posted.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean exactly
Would it help if i add the code that is before the error on the file?
Or what can i add to help fix this issue?